# Accessing a network scanner with JTWAIN

Tags: java, twain

The application I am working on is capable of scanning using a locally connected scanner, but I have been unable to find any information on how to access a networked scanners. Is it possible to achieve this with JTWAIN?

Comment: It's the same. As long as the networked scanner have TWAIN driver, you should be able to scan from it using the TWAIN SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes you can access it.**

> If that local machine has drivers installed for that scanner which is
>   connected then your twain dll will give a message to choose the
>   device.
>   It will scan it as per local scanner.

### Also that machine's browser must contain java. From java7 there are more security. It askes for permissions to access and you have to set it in your manifest.